# How implement RTPagingViewController with storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am using RTPagingViewController in my app,I used the objective c ones,and linked it to my swift project with a bridge.
it works as same as its demo.
there is a problem,when I scroll my view, view controller's codes compiled,for example,view did load triggered,but my storyboard and UIViewContollers that connected to ViewControllers doesn't show what I designed.
so I can't design my app with story board and I should do it programmatically.
How can I solve this problem ?

```
    class ViewController: RTPagingViewController {

let c1 = firstViewController()
let c2 = secondViewController()
let c3 = thirdViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.title = "RTPagingViewController"

    let indicator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.view.bounds.width / 3,height: 4))
    indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    //  indicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin
    self.titleIndicatorView = indicator

    c1.title = "first"
    // c1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    c2.title = "second"
    // c2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    c3.title = "third"
    //  c3.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    self.titleColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.selectedTitleColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    self.controllers = [c1,c2,c3]

    self.currentControllerIndex = 0



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the viewcontroller using storyboard id.

- Assign storyboard id in your storyboard.
  [image: Storyboard id]
- Instantiate the view controllers in viewDidLoad method.

  ```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
  let c1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController")
  let c2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")
  let c3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController")
  ```
- Put in your RTPagingViewController.

  ```
  self.controllers = [c1,c2,c3]
  ```